# selinux disabled, but still enforcing?

Tags: fedora, selinux

I have some systems where, for various reasons, we want to completely disable selinux. To date, this has worked like a champ, with always using selinux=0 in the kickstarts and ensuring that /etc/sysconfig/selinux contains:

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

But as of today, I have one Fedora 17 workstation that is properly set up, yet following many reboots, it always comes up in enforcing mode:

```
# cat /etc/sysconfig/selinux
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#     enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#     permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#     disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=disabled
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of these two values:
#     targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#     minimum - Modification of targeted policy. Only selected processes are protected. 
#     mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted 

# getenforce
Enforcing
```

What could be causing selinux to ignore the sysconfig entry, or to start despite it?

[Edit 1]

I saw a related question here and tried this:

```
# selinuxenabled ; echo $?
0
# getenforce
Enforcing
```

Comment: Try running setenforce 0

Comment: That just drops it from Enforcing to Permissive. It should be Disabled.

Comment: Is /etc/sysconfig/selinux a symbolic link to /etc/selinux/config? It should be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The actual config file is */etc/sellinux/config* to which */etc/sysconfig/selinux* links. It seems you might have lost the link and ended up with a regular file.

Verify that:

```
# ls -l /etc/sysconfig/selinux
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 17 Dec 22 18:59 /etc/sysconfig/selinux -> ../selinux/config
```

or check the contents of */etc/selinux/config*

Answer (score 0):

Running CentOS 8, I used this for scripts:

```
sed -i "s/SELINUX=.*/SELINUX=disabled/" /etc/selinux/config
```

Basically, you want the SELinux config file to have this setting

| **/etc/selinux/config** :

...if...

```
SELINUX=enabled
```

...change to...

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

While `sudo setenforce 0` will temporarily set it to "Permissive", changing the config file will permanently set it to "Disabled".