# Disable SeLinux permanently

Tags: centos6, selinux

I am running a virtualbox CentOS 6.4 (64 bit) server with Cobbler service. One of the steps is to disable SeLinux in order to prevent a python error when running `service cobblers start`. If I run `setenforce 0` everything is fine, but I have to run that command every time the server restarts. I tried changing `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` to `SELINUX=disabled` and also `SELINUX=permissive` before restarting, but sestatus keeps showing that centOS starts with selinux running. Do I need to change a different config file, or have I configured the selinux file incorrectly?

[Youtube video](http://youtu.be/hZzP-kOtGfU) showing selinux config file, rebooting and then checking status

Comment: It seems like this guy has the same issue in fedora:
http://serverfault.com/questions/500957/selinux-disabled-but-still-enforcing?rq=1

Comment: Disabling SELinux is never the right answer.  You should put it into Permissive mode, then use "sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log" to see what would be blocked in "Enforcing" mode.  Remedy those issues with either "restorecon" (mislabeled files), setting SELinux booleans, or using audit2allow to create a custom policy for your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set it in `/etc/selinux/config`

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#     enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#     permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#     disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=permissive
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of these two values:
#     targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#     minimum - Modification of targeted policy. Only selected processes are protected. 
#     mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

The correct location to pass selinux=0 as kernel boot paramater is in `/etc/grub.conf`

`kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64 ro root=/dev/xvda1 rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_LVM rd_NO_MD rd_NO_DM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us crashkernel=auto console=tty0 selinux=0`

PS SELinux should be only set to `permissive` to debug a problem, run it in `permissive` see what gets logged to `/var/log/audit.log` fix the denials then switch it back to `enforcing` do not run it in permissive or disabled long term.

Comment: When I originally read this answer I had not properly read the paths. I needed to change /etc/selinux/config instead of /etc/sysconfig/selinux as you stated.

Answer (score 3):

Setting `SELINUX=disabled` in the file `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` should be enough. You can also disable it from the kernel. Edit the file `/etc/default/grub` and add `selinux=0` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` variable and update your GRUB configuration:

```
shell# grub2-mkconfig -o /etc/grub2.cfg
```

After rebooting, check SELinux status. The `getenforce` command should print `Disabled`.

Comment: Ok well I have rebooted and used 'getenforce' instead of sestatus. It outputs Enforcing. Here is a video to show: http://youtu.be/hZzP-kOtGfU

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: It appears that I do not have a /etc/default/grub file. Perhaps I need to edit the /etc/grub.conf file? There is no GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX variable in there though.
Also grub2-mkconfig -o /etc/grub2.cfg resulted in `grub2-mkconfig: command not found`
Perhaps I should let you know that I am running a bare minimal centos 6.4 net-install...

Comment: @Programster, CentOS 6 is on Grub 1, IIRC. Thus, this part only works on CentOS 7 and later.